# How to prefetch cells in a TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, prefetch

I read about Prefetching and added the delegate, the datasource and the two functions required, now, what do I need to put in those two? Is this what's used to achieve 60 fps smooth scrolling?

Sorry if it's a vague question.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.prefetchDataSource = self

        let userJSONURLString = "https://qapital-ios-testtask.herokuapp.com/users"
        let activitiesJSONURLString = "https://qapital-ios-testtask.herokuapp.com/activities?from=2016-05-23T00:00:00+00:00&to=2019-05-23T00:00:00+00:00"
        guard let userURL = URL(string: userJSONURLString) else { return }
        guard let activitiesURL = URL(string: activitiesJSONURLString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: activitiesURL) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                // Activities
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                self.activities = result.activities

                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: userURL) { (data, response, err) in
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    do {
                        // Users
                        let usersJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                        guard let jsonArray = usersJson as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

                        for dic in jsonArray {
                            guard let avatarUrl = dic["avatarUrl"] as? String else { return }
                        }

                    } catch {
                        print("Error serializing json: ", error)
                    }
                    }.resume()
            } catch {
                print("Error serializing json: ", error)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        print("prefetching row of \(indexPaths)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        print("cancel prefetch row of \(indexPaths)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the source of your table view data?  If you have to fetch any of the content from the network (such as images) you can use the prefetch methods to fetch the images before the cell is actually displayed, that way you will have the immediately rather than showing a placeholder while the image loads.

Comment: Yes, I get them from a JSON API. You mean starting a URL Session inside the `prefetchRowsAt` method? I added a little bit of code (SO wont let me post much)

Comment: Ok, I can see that your data has an avatar URL - So you could prefetch the avatar images in the `prefetchRowAt` method.  Also I would suggest you look at `Codable` to convert your JSON to an object rather than decoding manually

Comment: I am using Decodable as I don't need to write data to the JSON, only read it. How would you prefetch the images in `prefetchRowAt`? Sorry, I'm kinda new at this. Thanks!

Comment: You aren't using `Decodable` correctly. - You shouldn't need to cast things to dictionary etc - You should end up with your desired structure. I would use something SDWebImage or Kingfisher to cache the images